# How to get all mp3 files on device

Tags: android

I have this code but it doesnt print any mp3 files. would be appreciated if you could help

```
public void getMp3Songs() {
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
               String songName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)+0 );
                System.out.println(songName);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        }
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all music files on the device.

```
        val selection = StringBuilder("is_music != 0 AND title != ''")

        // Display audios in alphabetical order based on their display name.
        val sortOrder = "${MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME} ASC"
        val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
            EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            selection.toString(),
            null,
            sortOrder
        )

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                val id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID))
                val title: String =
                    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME))
                val duration: Int =
                    cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION))
                val size = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE))
                val artist =
                  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST))
             } while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }
        cursor?.close()
```

Comment: It works but it is not returning mp3 files, instead it is returning ogg files. How do i fix this? @Varsha Kulkarni

Comment: It returns all types of audio files in my case. Please check if there are any mp3 files present on the device. If you need only mp3, check if `title.endsWith(".mp3")`.

Comment: I just realized, when i move the mp3 file to notifications folder of android, it shows the mp3 file. so it seems like this only checks system folders. by the way, i am using java @Varsha Kulkarni

Comment: From documentation, "Audio files, which are stored in the Alarms/, Audiobooks/, Music/, Notifications/, Podcasts/, and Ringtones/ directories. Additionally, the system recognizes audio playlists that are in the Music/ or Movies/ directories, as well as voice recordings that are in the Recordings/ directory. The system adds these files to the MediaStore.Audio table. The recordings directory isn't available on Android 11 (API level 30) and lower."

Comment: Where exactly are you looking to store the mp3 files?

Comment: I am looking for download folder

Comment: Please read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media)